# Trouble converting dates using _.LastWriteTime

Tags: powershell

I am writing a Powershell script that searches a network location and if the file was created in 2011 or 2012, then writes the filename to a log, as well as the sum of all 2011/12 files created.

I am getting an exception when it attempts to convert the date and time of file creation and compare it to my date range.

```
<#Checks one network location for files from 2011. 
gets the name of that file and adds to the count for 2011, then writes it to a log. 
Repeats for 2012.#>
    New-Item c:\users\logs\yearLog.txt -type file -force
    $path = "\\path"
    $log = "c:\users\log"
    $date2011 = "2011"
    $date2012 = "2012"
    write-progress -activity "Compiling Data" -status "Progress:"
    $x = 0
    "$date2011 files" | add-content $log

    Get-Childitem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (12/31/2010) -AND $_LastWriteTime -lt (01/01/2012) |
    ForEach {
        $filename = $_.fullname
        $x++
        "$filename" | add-content $movelog
    }

    "$date2011 total files = $x" | add-content $log
    $x = 0
    "$date2012 files" | add-content $log

    Get-Childitem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (12/31/2011) -AND $_LastWriteTime -lt (01/01/2013) |
    ForEach {
        $filename = $_.fullname
        $x++
        "$filename" | add-content $log
    }
    "$date2012 total files = $x" | add-content $log
}
}
```

Comment: Surround the date with quotation marks: *"12/31/2010"*. Otherwise it tries to divide 12 by 31 and then by 2010.

Comment: Thank you zespri. I should have caught that one :) Apparently, that isn't my only problem

Comment: Post the exception text please

Comment: Add-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. "$filename" | add-content <<<< $movelog

Comment: movelog wasn't declared and mistyped... However, it isn't working! There are no further exceptions, but it just runs and creates a file that says "2011 total files 0  <br/> 2012 total files 1 <br/> 2012 total files 2 ...etc. I think that I am missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key Issue: Your braces in the Where clause are unbalanced and the pipeline is broken.

Additional fixes:

- Compare year directly since you already have a DateTime object
- Used formatting for variables in strings, It's just easier when you start dealing with indexes
- Use -Begin clause on ForEach to initialize counter

Anyway, here's a fixed version, converted to a function so you can pick any path, year, and select the log output folder

```
function YearLog {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$LogFolder,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][Int]$Year
    )

    $log = '{0}\FileLog-{1}.txt' -f $LogFolder, $Year

    if(Test-Path -Path:$log) { 
        Remove-Item -Force -Path:$log 
    }

    'Files Found for {0}:' -f $Year | add-content $log

    Get-Childitem -Path $Path -Recurse | 
        Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime.Year -gt ($Year-1)) -AND ($_.LastWriteTime.Year -lt ($Year+1)) } |
        ForEach -Begin { $x = 0 } -Process {
            $x++ | Out-Null
            $_.FullName | add-content $log
        }

    'Total Found for {0}: {1}' -f $year, $x  | add-content $log
    'Log written for items in {0} for {1}: {2}' -f $Path, $Year, $log | Write-Host 
}

<# Usage:     
   YearLog -Path:$ENV:ProgramFiles -LogFolder:$ENV:TEMP -Year:2012
#>
```